# Is it possible to bind event to Observable field directly with BindingAdapter?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm writing a binding adapter for bottom sheet provided by android-support-design library. What I'm trying to achieve is to bind the state change event to an observable field, thus avoid glue code of event handler completely.

```
public class BottomSheetBindingAdapter {

    @BindingAdapter("behavior_onStateChange")
    public static void bindBottomSheetStateChange(final View view, final ObservableInt state) {
        final BottomSheetBehavior<View> behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view);
        if (behavior == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(view + " has no BottomSheetBehavior");
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetCallback() {

            @Override public void onStateChanged(@NonNull final View bottomSheet, final int new_state) {
                state.set(new_state);
            }

            @Override public void onSlide(@NonNull final View bottomSheet, final float slideOffset) {}
        });
    }
}
```

In layout XML:

```
bind:behavior_onStateChange="@{apps.selection.bottom_sheet_state}"
```

where "bottom_sheet_state" is a field of ObservableInt.

Then compiler warns: `Cannot find the setter for attribute 'bind:behavior_onStateChange' with parameter type int.` Seems like the data binding compiler always treat ObservableInt field as int when matching a BindingAdapter.

How can I actually write a BindingAdapter to bind an event handler to change the Observable field, without glue code in view-model class?

Comment: If you just change your observable by an int (in the custom binding method only), and remplace the `state.set(new_state)` by `state = new_state`, the bound ObservableInt property of your model will be updated when the "onStateChanged" handler will be called.

Comment: @PaulDS How is that even possible? The method parameter in primitive type is "passing by value". `state = new_state` will only change the value of the parameter `state` within the method scope.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. The solution I found in my application is to create my own custom observable (I need it for other things, not only this case). You can find my example here : https://github.com/Paul-DS/SimpleFTP/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/paulds/simpleftp/presentation/binders/FormBindings.java but I don't know if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change `ObservableInt` value in `BindingAdapter` and expect it to be reflected in the View Model. What you want here i**s Two-way binding**. Since there is no `bottomSheetState` attribute provided out of the box, we need to create the two way binding by creating `InverseBindingAdapter`.

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(
    attribute = "bottomSheetState",
    event = "android:bottomSheetStateAttrChanged"
)
fun getBottomSheetState(view: View): Int {
    return BottomSheetBehavior.from(view).state
}
@BindingAdapter(value = ["android:bottomSheetStateAttrChanged"], requireAll = false)
fun View.setBottomSheetStateListener(inverseBindingListener: InverseBindingListener) {
    val bottomSheetCallback = object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, @BottomSheetBehavior.State newState: Int) {
            inverseBindingListener.onChange()
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
    }
    BottomSheetBehavior.from(this).addBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback)
}
```

BTW, this is kotlin code. Add this in any of the kt file in top level. Then you can use like `app:bottomSheetState="@={viewModel.bottomSheetState}"` in the xml whereas `bottomSheetState` is `ObservableInt`.

Now you can observe on `bottomSheetState` for state change in bottom sheet.